# Jupyter Notebook print to PDF prints unexpected text

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, latex, pandoc, xelatex

I have been having issue downloading a Jupyter Notebook to PDF. My original error was

> Solving "500: Internal Server Error, nbconvert failed: xelatex not found in PATH".

For this I ran from Anaconda Prompt:

```
conda install -c conda-forge miktex
```

To solve this I ran from Python Command Prompt:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf C:\Users\myProfile\myFile.ipynb
```

I then got an error about Pandoc missing and so to solve this I ran from Anaconda Prompt:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pandoc
```

I'm now able to create a pdf but it has one page of gibberish and the actual text is not formatted.

The following in a markdown cell:

```
<h1>Test Presentation</h1>
<h2>Today's Date</h2>
<h3>Author</h3>
```

produces:
[image]

I also have MikTex and Pandoc installed on my computer and have added their paths to my System Properties Environment Variables. I get no error messages but this gibberish of a PDF.

Comment: Can you add the input and the command you used for the conversion? The first three lines of `pandoc -v` would be helpful, too.

Answer (score 0):

try the following steps:

from your command prompt install [notebook-as-pdf](https://pypi.org/project/notebook-as-pdf/) (here are [snyk](https://snyk.io/advisor/python/notebook-as-pdf) and [deps](https://deps.dev/pypi/notebook-as-pdf/0.5.0) scurity analysis*)

```
pip install -U notebook-as-pdf
```

you also need an additional setup for chromium (performs HTML to PDF conversion - [snyk](https://snyk.io/advisor/python/pyppeteer), [deps](https://deps.dev/pypi/pyppeteer))

```
pyppeteer-install
```

open the notebook you wish to convernt, click on **file** -> **Download As** -> **PDF via HTML**,
if you prefer you can run it from your command prompt:

```
jupyter-nbconvert --to PDFviaHTML example.ipynb
```

---

- note that it has a mid-low score because the last commit was on april, on the other hand it has no dependencies so from that angle you are good